# How is RefreshingView different from ListView?

Tags: java, wicket

In Wicket how does a `RefreshingView` differ from a `ListView` as far as it's working is concerned? I know that the `RefreshingView` has a method that returns the iterator of the model but what are the use cases which necessitates using a `RefreshingView` instead of a `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

Listview is something you want to use to show static readonly content because of its nature of not reusing the items and generating fresh on every request. You could set to reuse the items, but then you don't have much fine grained control on how not to display stale data; so basically use list view for static kind of data or historical data in report form.

Refreshing view is something you want to use to show dynamic data as the name suggest. Also, with custom item reuse strategy, you get better control on display.